# How to replace "y" in cor(x,y) with different variables so it will loop to find correlation on each different variable?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm very new with the R language, apologies for the noob question.

I'm trying to find a correlation between **sex** and total Usability (totalU), total Satisfaction (totalS), and total Ease of Use (totalE). Also, sexNumeric is basically Male = 1, Female = 2, vice versa.

For efficiency purposes, I'd like to learn about how you can loop this.
I've tried doing:

```
x <- sexNumeric 
z <- list(totalU,totalS,totalE)

for (i in z){
  cor(x,z)
}
```

But it does not work, it says "Error in cor(x,z) : 'y' must be numeric."

Here is the link of the csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MlmaLGFpm94dLssMAX6oFj0_P5chuUJi/view?usp=sharing

Here is a reproducible sample:

```
dat <- read.csv(file = "Canva_ApplicationUsability.csv", header = TRUE) 
totalU = rowSums(dat[,c(4:8)],na.rm=TRUE) #Get the sum of each respondent in Usefulness
totalS = rowSums(dat[,c(9:13)],na.rm=TRUE) #Get the sum of each respondent in Satisfaction
totalE = rowSums(dat[,c(14:18)],na.rm=TRUE)  #Get the sum of each respondent in Ease of Use

#Assign Numeric Values to Characters of Sex
sexNumeric <- dat[1]
sexNumeric <- sexNumeric %>% mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex == "Male", 1))
sexNumeric <- sexNumeric %>% mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex == "Female", 2))
sexNumeric <- sexNumeric %>% mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex == "Transgender Male", 3))
sexNumeric <- sexNumeric %>% mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex == "Transgender Female", 4)) 
sexNumeric <- sexNumeric %>% mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex == "Gender Variant/Non-Conforming", 5)) 
sexNumeric <- sexNumeric %>% mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex == "Prefer Not to Answer", 6))
sexNumeric$Sex <- as.numeric(sexNumeric$Sex)
```

So yeah, those are the where sexNumeric and totalU, totalS, and totalE come from. Then, I'd like to find the correlation between sexNumeric (x) and totalU, totalS, and totalE (y) in one loop.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Specifically, for every loop, I want z to be replaced by totalU, then in the next loop replaced by totalS, then in the next by totalE. Each of those  variables contain values ranging from 1 to 5, it's from a Likert-scale survey.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  You are looping over `z`, so, inside the loop `cor(x, i)`?

Comment: @akrun Hello, thanks for your answer. What is a small reproducible example? Also, I think loop is an incorrect way of doing this, but it's the only method I can think of. Since, if I'll use `i` in `cor(x,i)`, wouldn't it just add number 1? What I want to do is, for every loop, z will be replaced by totalU, then in the next loop, z will be replaced by totalS, then in the next by totalE.

Comment: A reproducible example is one which others can test.  Your post shows only code, and it is not clear about the structure of `totalU` etc.

Comment: According to `?cor`, the `x` or `y` can be vector/data.frame/matrix.  So you may do `cor(x, do.call(cbind, z))`

Comment: @akrun I added a reproducible sample. And will try your suggestion! Thanks.

Comment: @akrun The code works, what a genius. So, it turns out, I don't have to use for loop... If you have the time, would be willing to explain how the code works? I don't understand how `do.call(cbin,z)` works.

Comment: It is just that you created ` list` of vectors.  which when `cbind` returns a matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?cor`, `x` can be a vector, matrix or data.frame, similarly, if we provide `y`, it can be as well.  From the `list` of `vector`s, we can `cbind` the elements to create to a single matrix and use that in `cor`

```
cor(x, do.call(cbind, z))
```

the `do.call` with `cbind` does the same as

```
cbind(z[[1]], z[[2]], z[[3]])
```

in a compact way i.e if there are 100s of list elements, we don't have to extract each element separately for `cbind`ing

Answer (score 0):

You can provide more than one `numeric` variable to `cor()`, it will return a correlation *matrix*:

```
data("trees") #build-in dataset
cor(trees)

           Girth    Height    Volume
Girth  1.0000000 0.5192801 0.9671194
Height 0.5192801 1.0000000 0.5982497
Volume 0.9671194 0.5982497 1.0000000
```

Comment: Hello, Oliver. Are you suggesting I should do `cor(x,totalU,totalS,totalE)`? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Not quite, you can provide the whole data.frame to cor(). However, every variable has to be continuous - otherwise, the result will not be statistically correct. Categorial variables (like Sex, ...) can't be analyzed that way - even when decoded numerically. So strictly said, you can only follow this approach for the columns U1-E4 in your linked dataset.